# Word for something that can be obsolete in the future, obsolete-able

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, is-it-a-word

Done → Doable

Destroyed → Destructible

Consumed → Consumable

Obsolete → ???

The word "Obsoletable" is listed some ~ 34,000 times in Google; however, I can't find it in dictionaries, which makes me think people coined it looking for the same word I am trying to find.

Comment: Well, it is in the OED, the first of the four listed adjectival senses being *No longer used or practised; outmoded, out of date.* But the only term I can think of, for what you need is *of limited lifespan*.

Comment: I wonder whether this is relevant: the first 3 examples can be preceded by a bare "can be"; with *obsolete*, you can't - you need "can be *made*".

Comment: So, it's **"not future-proof"**

Comment: @Lawrence it is not as much "can be _made_" as it is "can _become_", i.e. it's a property or innate characteristic of the thing that it can _become obsolete_, with no expectancy or reference to the external factor needed nor that it will or will not become obsolete, much like "Doable", of course someone will have to "Do" it before it _becomes_ "Done", but "Doable" itself does not necessarily refer to that, also it implies that it has not been "Done" yet with no reference of whether or not it will be "Done".

Maybe I'm over-thinking this however :)

Comment: "Ephemeral", "short-lived" or "temporary"?

Comment: @pjc50 "Ephemeral", "short-lived" and "temporary" suggest that no other possibility than obsolescence, just a question of when.

Comment: @Lawrence though I do not agree that "obsolete" can't be preceded by a bare "can be", as I see "can be obsolete" a perfectly viable use of words; I guess you are right that the 3 examples hold a common point that "obsolete" does not, which is the fact that the adjective is the past-participle of the verb, which is not the case for "obsolete".

Comment: *outdoable*: also not in dictionaries and scores a 76 at most on Google ;)

Comment: It may be too narrow (hence not an answer), but in computer science we use "deprecated". It means it's shortlisted to go away. Don't use it.

Comment: It seems to me that *everything* that could be considered obsolete or non-obsolete is "Obosletable", so it makes sense that there is no word that describes something common to everything.

Comment: No to obsoletable.  Because obsolete isn't a verb, y'know.

Comment: Deprecatable? Just a thought

Comment: @James Not so. The OED has a verb references with examples from as long ago as 1640 to the present day. *trans. To render obsolete. Formerly (also): †to consider obsolete; to discard as being out of date, to cease to produce or use (obs.).* There is also an adverb listed *obsoletely*- *In an obsolete or outdated manner; (Biol.) indistinctly.*, but sadly no adjective.

Comment: @WS2 wow, never heard that before!  In the dictionary it's listed as a verb only in the US.  I would have considered obsolesce.

Comment: _**Technology**_ (More specifically, anything made by Apple.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You might consider, [***obsolescence-prone***](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22obsolescence+prone%22&biw=531&bih=348&prmd=nvi&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiu-8X09obMAhWIVywKHSX5DM4Q_AUICygG&dpr=2) and ***obsolescent-/obsolete-prone***

> *If you're concerned about the problems of owning or maintaining rundown, obsolescence-prone freight equipment, talk it over with U.S. Railway Equipment Company. Chances are we'll have some interesting dollar-saving suggestions.*
>
> *During periods when business generally is slumping, the profit picture is helped by the fact that the real estate man need hold no large investment in buildings, equipment, or obsolete-prone products.*
>
> [Adult Education Through Home Study](https://books.google.fr/books?id=uggWAAAAMAAJ&q=%22obsolete-prone%22&dq=%22obsolete-prone%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjN8Lvlm4bMAhXGlxoKHetbCXEQ6AEIWTAI)

Also, ***planned*** (*or* ***built-in***) ***obsolescence***, as in

> *Planned or Built-In Obsolescence products are designed to fail within a given period of time* [...]
>
> [prezi.com](https://prezi.com/m/kfyy_dgjge99/obsolesence/)
>
> **planned obsolescence**
>
> : a method of stimulating consumer demand by designing products that wear out or become outmoded after limited use. Also called **built-in obsolescence**.
>
> [Random House](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/built-in-obsolescence)

Comment: **obsolete-prone** seems like a very accurate match, and it's what I will be using, I will just leave the question open till tomorrow for the remote possibility that someone has a better answer.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The only problem I see with **obsolete-prone** is that **prone** holds the possibility for obsolescence favourable, I want something that holds both possibilities equal.

Comment: *Obsolescence-prone* feels more natural to me than *obsolete-prone* (i.e. nounal rather than adjectival form).

Comment: @MysticOdin what about obsolescence-sensitive?

Comment: @Graffito like I noted for many suggestions, we need a word that carries both the possibility of something becomeing obsolete and not becoming obsolete equally, "on the way to obsolescence" has a single word match which is **obsolescent**, the problem is that it means it will definitely become obsolete, not only the possibility.

Comment: @MysticOdin - an alternative to obsolescence-prone is "subject to  obsolescence".

Answer (score 10):

[Obviable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obviable):

> capable of being obviated

And since *obviate* doesn't get the recognition it deserves...

[Obviate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obviated):

> to make (something) no longer necessary : to prevent or avoid
>   (something)

Comment: Obviate is a lovely word, and I quite agree that it doesn’t get the recognition it deserves, but I’m not sure it fits the bill here.  Obsolescing is very different from being obviated.  My iPhone will obsolesce in a few years when better iPhones have come out; it would be obviated if some company developed mass-market telepathic internet/phone implants.

Comment: And Apple would be obliviated if they didn't sell other products than iPhones

Answer (score 9):

The common thread among your first three examples is that they are *verbs*. Things that are *able* to 'do' those verbs may then be suffixed with *-able*.

This is the same with other words like *write* (writeable), *read* (readable), *eat* (eatable / edible), etc.

*Obsolete* is not normally considered to be a verb (it's an adjective), so is modified differently (e.g. *obsolescence*).

The following dictionary entry mentions that *obsolete* may be used as a verb:

> **Obsolete** *verb*
>   [with object] *chiefly US*
>   Cause (a product or idea) to become obsolete by replacing it with something new: *we’re trying to stimulate the business by obsoleting last year’s designs*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolete)

The form *obsoletable* may be used in that sense. Here's an example:

> Coloring the cards only works for nonperishable and non-obsoletable items.
>   [- Manufacturing Consulting Services, Inc](http://www.leanmfg.com/why-us/real-results-case-studies/diamond-drill-bit-manufacturing-company)

As [@PLL notes](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318820/word-for-something-that-can-be-obsolete-in-the-future-obsolete-able/318843#comment725513_318886), *obsolesce* is the proper verb form of *obsolete*. Here's the dictionary entry

> **Obsolesce** *derived verb*
>   (derived from obsolescent: Becoming obsolete)
>   *existing systems begin to obsolesce*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolescent?q=obsolesce#obsolescent__4)

Comment: Obsolete, like you mentioned, can be used as a verb, and the point exactly is that _obsoletable_ is not word I can find in dictionaries, though I agree that using it as a coined expression is not really that bad.

Comment: @MysticOdin I've updated my answer with the proper verb form.

Answer (score 4):

Something that is *becoming obsolete* is [**obsolescent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolescent).

> ***adjective***
>
> 1. becoming obsolete; passing out of use, as a word: *an obsolescent term.*
> 2. becoming outdated or outmoded, as machinery or weapons.
> 3. Biology. gradually disappearing or imperfectly developed, as vestigial organs.

So, any object that *can become obselete* is [**obsolescent**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/obsolescent) to some extent.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a single word, but this meaning seems to exist already as an established term in the business sector:  ***"obsolescence risk"***

http://www.investopedia.com/terms/o/obsolescencerisk.asp

Companies can be discussed in terms of their obsolescence risk or "obsolescence factor".

I think that the reason there isn't a word for "potentially obsolete" is that it applies to everything:  nothing is immune from becoming obsolete.  So, while there are lots of things that are very hard to destroy, hard to consume or hard to do, so we need both words for each of those cases (indestructable/fragile, edible/inedible, possible/impossible), i think there is an implicit assumption that everything is potentially obsolete and so we don't really need a special word for it.  Which isn't to say there shouldn't be one.

So it might be that you're actually looking for a word to describe something with a **high obsolescence risk/factor**, ie that is relatively likely to become obsolete **more quickly**.  I have a feeling that there is a word or term for this:  perhaps ***"not futureproofed"***?

Comment: risk or factor imply that something needs to be done about the fact, not futureproofed is, like you said, "relatively likely to become obsolete more quickly".

I see your point about "potentially obsolete", for example words like "agreeable" and "likable" do not mean that it carries the potential to be agreed or liked, they mean "to one's liking", probably for the same reason you mentioned that nothing is immune to being agreed, liked, disliked, or disagreed, however; I do not think "obsolete" is the same, for example nothing can make Van Gogh's art obsolete but you can like it or dislike it.

Comment: @MysticOdin you're right, actually, there's plenty of things which are immune to being obsolete.  So, I suppose that's not the reason this word doesn't exist...

Answer (score 2):

How about **supersedable**?

Wiktionary: 'Capable of being **superseded**' - *"This document is temporary and supersedable"*

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly use **obsolescence**, depending on your context.

From vocabulary.com:

> The word obsolescence is the noun form of the more common obsolete, meaning "something no longer used." Both words stem from the Latin obsolēscere, which means, logically enough, "to fall into disuse."

An example of it's usage would be, "The Harley Davidson was designed to go out of fashion rapidly - it was an example of planned obsolescence"

Comment: I think obsolescence is the process of becoming obsolete, but it's not the state that it has *now* which i think is what the question is after.

Comment: I think you're right, however in the context of the original question, couldn't you use Obsolete for the future tense as well as the present?

Comment: @AaronLavers Using obsolescence will change the structure of the sentence, so instead of "this feature is obsolete-prone" I would use "the obsolescence of this feature is possible", so there is definitely a way to rephrase the sentence to carry out the same meaning, but the aim of the question is exactly not to do that.

"Obsolete" can be used for the future of course, however the word I am looking for should mean that it "can be obsolete" and equally "can be not obsolete", i.e. to signify the possibility without preference to whether it will happen.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a lot of answers and discussions within the comments, for the sake of benefiting the StackExchange reading public, so that they do not miss this useful information, also so that they do explore threads already concluded, I am going to post this answer as a summary of these discussions and their conclusions.

1. There is no perfect answer (so far), to carry the meaning perfectly the sentence needs to be rephrased using **obsolescence** and **possible**.
2. The closest answer to the word in question, which is the answer I am selecting as correct, is [Elian's Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/318831/169770), ***obsolescence-prone***, thanks to [atkins](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/16287/atkins) for suggesting the improvement from the original ***obsolete-prone***, this is not a perfect answer because **prone** suggest probability not simple possibility.
3. [Max Willams' Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/318827/169770) suggested ***obsolescence risk/factor***, the problem is that **risk** and **factor** suggest that something needs to be done about the fact, **not future-proofed** suggests, even more strongly than ***obsolescence-prone***, that it is likely to become obsolete.
4. In the same answer Mr. Willams suggested that may be this is because nothing is immune from being obsolete, we then agreed that for a thing to become obsolete it has to be something (e.g. a tool) that can be replaced by something that is *objectively better*, and that Art for example is immune to be obsolete because it cannot be judged to be objectively better, for example we cannot burn Van Gogh's painting on the premise that they are obsoleted by another painter's paintings.
5. [Lawrence's Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/318843/169770) suggested that this may be because "obsolete" is not a verb, however; "obsolete" indeed is a verb, the basic difference between the example Do → Done → Doable is that the adjective is the past-participle of the verb, but we did not reach a conclusion there.
6. [Michael Fredrickson's Answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/318886/169770) suggests the word **obviable**, which is excellent in carrying the possibility without favouring it actually happening, however; "Obviate" is different in meaning than "Obsolete", an obsolete object is an object that has been replaced by a better object to fulfill the same task, an obviated object is an object that is no longer being used because the task it fulfilled is itself obsolete, check out [PLL's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318820/word-for-something-that-can-be-obsolete-in-the-future-obsolete-able?noredirect=1#comment725513_318886) for an excellent example.
7. Using *Obsoletable* as a coined expression is not that bad IMHO, however; it defeats the purpose of the question, which is to have a word that is present in the English language to carry out that meaning.
8. Several people suggested **obsolescent**, **obsolescent** means *becoming obsolete*, not simply noting the possibility that it may or may not happen, it means it will be obsolete, just a question of when, that is why obsolescent, and many other suggestions for that matter, are not seen as a correct match.

Comment: You've asked for a single word answer in your question, then ignored the single word answer that is closest in meaning from your round up. Do you have a particular problem with `obsolecent`?

Comment: @Jodrell obsolescence and obsolescent mean it is becoming obsolete, not possibly, definitely, it was suggested, but you are correct that I did not put it in my round up, I will correct this mistake.

Comment: Anything that can be obsolete will, given enough time, become so. I think that `obsolescent` is so often misused interchangeably with obsolete, or to indicate short term obsolescence the implicit non-determinism over time is overlooked. If you consider, we don't really need a word that means "might become obsolete but not soon," What would it apply too, bar most everything?

Comment: Something that is _edible_ for example will not necessarily be eaten given enough time.

As for not needing a word because it applies to everything, i.e. nothing is immune from being obsolete; the same argument was made by Max Williams, and this I included in the summary, we agreed that a lot of things are immune to being obsolete like Art, you will not replace art with something objectively better.

Comment: Another real life example, car parts, I can say that a car part is "obsolete-able", i.e. it may or may not happen that you, or the manufacturer, opt for a better part for the same car, the possibility here is to indicate that the car is designed in a way to allow that to happen, not in a way that this part has to be exactly identical to be replaced, which is actually the typical case.

Answer (score -1):

I'd most likely use this in the vein of being potentially or permissibly obsolete, e.g. a code library that is likely to be deprecated. In other words, one can assume it's okay to retire or ignore this item. I wish obsoletable was already a word and suggest using it so that it does become officially adopted by major dictionaries.