# Word for a statement which would not be true in the future?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I am trying to explain to somebody why the statement “technology A will soon replace technology B” is not a good idea to write in a book.

The reason I want to provide is that, in a few years time, indeed technology A might have replaced technology B, in which case the statement “will soon replace” will not be true anymore.

I am searching for a single word or a short phrase to describe statements like this, which are currently true but will not be true in the future.

---

### Example

> This is another example of a ________ statement, since you would need to update it in a few years’ time.

---

### Research

I have tried to use a search engine to find a suitable word, and to think of something myself, but without much success.

The best I could come up with is “non-future-proof”, which is vague and also describes what these statements are not instead of what they are. Another word is “short-lived”, but I find it a bit too general.

---

### Similar Question

[Word for something that can be obsolete in the future, obsolete-able](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/318820/word-for-something-that-can-be-obsolete-in-the-future-obsolete-able) sounds similar, but there is a significant distinction.

The definition of obsolete, according to Oxford Languages, is

> no longer produced or used

A statement like this does not become “obsolete”, as in “no longer produced or used”. Instead, it becomes no longer true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is another example of a **time-sensitive** statement, since you
> would need to update it in a few years.

**time-sensitive**

> 2. only relevant or applicable for a short period of time
>
> Most secrets are **time-sensitive** and cease to be of interest to anyone but
> historians 20 or 30 years later. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/time-sensitive)

> Truths are **time-sensitive**. They equate to our now. A truth for us
> today, may not hold as true for us in five years. And the fact that it
> was a truth five years ago and isn't now, doesn't mean it was any less
> true then.  *[Into Your Meditation](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Into_Your_Meditation_Metaphors_On_Essent/sy9nCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22time-sensitive%22%20truths&pg=PT30&printsec=frontcover)* (2016)

> You see, God's word is not **time-sensitive**, meaning the truth of
> God's word is not affected by deadlines, or the lack thereof. *[50
> Days of Faith for Entrepreneurs](https://www.google.com/books/edition/50_Days_of_Faith_for_Entrepreneurs/xuhpCwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22time-sensitive%22%20truths&pg=PA55&printsec=frontcover)* p.55

Comment: Usage... But really horrible.

Answer (score 1):

I like one of Greybeard's suggestions in the comments:

*This is a statement which is true only **transitorily.***

Here [*transitory*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transitory) means 'tending to pass away: not persistent'.

Answer (score 1):

***Situational***

> *This is another example of a **situational** statement, since you would need to update it in a few years’ time.*

See:

> **situation** *noun*
>
> **5 a** : relative position or combination of circumstances at a certain moment
>
> <sub>Source: [Merriam-Webster —
> *situation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/situation)</sub>

The adjective *situational* means ***relating to** a relative position or combination of circumstances at a certain moment*.

“That was then — this is now.”

Of course, this does not mean that the situational statement definitely *won’t* be true in the future — only that it *might not* be.